# Pandas groupby datetime and column then apply generates ValueError

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group my dataframe and then apply a function to each row of the dataframe:

```
df=pd.read_csv('stack.csv')
df['TIME_M']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME_M'],format='%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
df.groupby(['SYM_ROOT',df['TIME_M'].dt.date]).apply(group_increment_to_end)

def group_increment_to_end(x):
    return x.iloc[0:1]
```

`SYM_ROOT` is a category variable, while `TIME_M` is a datetime variable.

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Key 2017-01-03 00:00:00 not in level Index([2017-01-03], dtype='object', name=u'TIME_M')
```

Do you know what is the cause of the problem? Is it because of the fact that iloc cannot be applied to a function with multiple indices? What if I want to iterate through the rows and add rows with the `group_increment_to_end` function, how should I do that, if I can't use the iloc function?

UPDATE:

The dataset can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ult5av644qlojfn/stack.csv?dl=0).

```
| SYM_ROOT | TIME_M                     | BEST_BID | BEST_ASK | increment | genjud_incre | 
|----------|----------------------------|----------|----------|-----------|--------------| 
| A        | 2017-01-03 09:30:00.004712 | 45.91    | 46.12    | 0         | 4680         | 
| AA       | 2017-01-03 09:30:00.004014 | 28.55    | 28.57    | 0         | 4680         |
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael I added the link to the data. It just contains two rows, a very simple dataset.

Comment: @jezrael I also attached a text version of the dataset.

Comment: It seems like bug :(

Comment: @JinhuaWang you are trying to group by df['TIME_M'].dt.date which is '2017-01-03 00:00:00', it cannot group on this thats why error. try this and it will work df.groupby(['SYM_ROOT',df['TIME_M']]).apply(group_increment_to_end)

Comment: @min2bro But I need to group by date not time though.

Comment: @jezrael Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JinhuaWang Add a new column and split date and time and then grouo by Date. Let me know if you need the code.

Comment: @min2bro Yes I think you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @min2bro I think I know the answer.

The problem is with `df['TIME_M'].dt.date` , which is an object with date and void time `2017-01-03 00:00:00` . However, grouping by this object returns error because somehow pandas doesn't recognize the date object correctly when parsing columns.

The correct way would be separating the date out alone as a column and grouping by that object instead.